# Rails 5 routing spec requires :path value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading Rails 4.2.8 to 5.0, all of my routing specs are failing with the same error message:

```
1) UsersController routing routes to SHOW
     Failure/Error: expect(get: '/users/joe-smith').to route_to('users#show', id: 'joe-smith')

       The recognized options <{"path"=>"users/joe-smith", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"joe-smith"}> did not match <{"id"=>"joe-smith", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"show"}>, difference:.
       --- expected
       +++ actual
       @@ -1 +1 @@
       -{"id"=>"joe-smith", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"show"}
       +{"path"=>"users/joe-smith", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"joe-smith"}
     # ./spec/routing/users_controller_routing_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.05154 seconds (files took 6.86 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/routing/users_controller_routing_spec.rb:9 # UsersController routing routes to SHOW
```

The spec:

```
it 'routes to SHOW' do
  expect(get: '/users/joe-smith').to route_to('users#show', id: 'joe-smith')
end
```

Anyone have any insight into WHY this is happening? I didn't see anything in the Rails 5 CHANGELOG.

Comment: And what's an elegant fix outside of replicating the path?

Comment: Using `.to route_to` specs are pretty worthless in the first place. You should have at least one feature or request spec that should cover this anyways.

Comment: As to why - it may not actually be a published change in Rails. It could be a regression in RSpec-Rails.

Answer (score 2):

A better fix is to start the move to a more [future proof method](https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html) of testing that provides more value:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "Users", type: :request do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  describe "GET /users/:id" do
    it "takes a username as the id param" do
       get user_path(user.user_name)
       expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it's a bit debatable at what level you should test for any given application and feature. some people are biased towards faster, more reliable, unit tests and some (maybe @max?) are biased towards acceptance tests which provide more realistic coverage. this might be right solution for the op, but i'm not sure it's a great solution for everyone.

Comment: Adding a bunch of useless low level specs that duplicate things you should have covered with integration specs is not faster.

Comment: And if anything the changes in Rails 5 signal very clearly that the community does not regard unit testing controllers as a good practice. Its debatable - but  I would say the debate is pretty much over at this point.